# Is it possilble to run tests with cypress cucumber preprocessor but only for ui tests?

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

How can I configure cypress to use cypress-cucumber-preprocessor for ui tests and use the standard way to run api tests?

Comment: What's stopping you from doing that? You can create your UI tests with Cucumber feature files and step definitions and write normal Cypress tests for API testing. Using the preprocessor does not mean you cannot use normal Cypress tests anymore. They are working like before. I also used a similar setup just recently. In case there are any issues you need to add more details to the question.

Comment: Well, you're right no additional configuration is needed.
I've tought that the usage of cucumber-preprocessor wouldn't let me run both ways. Thanks.